Cron Job analytics_subscribe has an error
Cron jobs seem to halt to this error in cron.log:
main.ERROR: Cron Job analytics_subscribe has an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (DATABASENAME.oauth_token, CONSTRAINT OAUTH_TOKEN_CONSUMER_ID_OAUTH_CONSUMER_ENTITY_ID FOREIGN KEY (consumer_id) REFERENCES oauth_consumer (entity_id) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO oauth_token (consumer_id, type, token, secret, verifier, callback_url, user_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":237502464,"emalloc_start":234244904} [] []
I have Magento 2.4.5-p1, PHP7.4, Elasticsearch 7.17
Any ideas what causes this?
